# How to draw on TCanvas with performance?

Tags: delphi

I use a map component named TatukGis and I need to draw some other information on map, it uses TCanvas basically to draw the maps. 
 I'm working with Pixels to create an alpha blend effect that I'd like, but it's very slow, it seems to refresh the canvas on each operation. Some one can give some hints how to use TCanvas in the correctly way to draw the things fast ?

Tks

Comment: Yes, the `Pixels` property is *very* slow. It's almost unusable. You have to access the pixels via the `Scaline` property. [The second sample in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4916913/draw-opacity-ellipse-in-delphi-2010/4917296#4917296) might be useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First write to a bitmap (use ScanLine if you require pixel access), then draw the bitmap to the canvas (CopyRect).

Comment: Or StretchBlt, which despite the name might actually be faster than copyrect.

Comment: Or `BitBlt` if you don't need to stretch.

Comment: BitBlt is (usually?) faster than StretchBlt.  As long as your bitmaps are 1:1.

Comment: Or TranslateBlt in msimg32.dll. Not win95 compatible, but iirc it used to be faster that bitblt, but with less features

Comment: StretchBlt=BitBlt when no stretch required

Comment: @Marco: Really, I have to look that up.

Comment: Andreas: saw a reference once, but at that time we already decided to convert to OpenGL, so I didn't look into it, or verify it further, other than that it exists. I do know that many webcam viewer programs use it. (from viewing with PEExplorer)